# Matlab programming code understanding

Tags: matlab

I have come across a matlab code that I am unable to understand. If anybody knows what this code means then help me in this regard.

```
Lambda(:,1) = [randi([1,4], 1,4), randi([1,30],1)*rand];
```

I do know that `randi` will return random integer between [min, max]. What I would like to know, that what lambda will receive? **a row values**, **a column values** or **only a scalar value**?

Answer (score 1):

Well.. You could just run the code and see what happens:

```
[randi([1,4], 1,4), randi([1,30],1)*rand]
ans =
    4.0000    2.0000    4.0000    1.0000   11.9046
```

So the answer will be: a row vector with 5 entries.

But let's look at it more detailed: With `randi([1,4], 1,4)` you create a row vector of size `1 x 4`, containing random integers between `[min,max]`, i.e. between `1` and `4`. The second part similarly creates one integer in the range `[1,30]` and multiplies it by a random number from the interval `(0,1)`.
With `[x,y]` you concatenate the two numbers or vectors. This leads to a row vector of size `1 x 5`, as we saw in the beginning.

In the end you assign this to `Lambda(:,1)`. As in MATLAB the first index is for rows and the second for columns, you select the first column of `Lambda`. You are thus trying to assign a `1 x 5` row vector to a `5 x 1` column vector. Luckily MATLAB is smart enough to handle that, so this snippet will work anyways. It would be a nicer and more clear solution, if you created a column vector instead of a row vector in the first place. That would be

```
Lambda(:,1) = [randi([1,4], 4,1); randi([1,30],1)*rand];
```